# simple Sand Pile code in JAVA

Tags: java, cellular-automata

does anyone know where I could find the source code for the SandPile (cellular Automata)? 
 thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following has a Sand Pile cellular automata Java Applet with source:
http://www.larssono.com/musings/sandpile/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
@Service("sandpileAddition")
public class SandpileAddition
{
   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( SandpileAddition.class );
   /**
    * 
    * @param n
    * @param limitSupCase
    * @param row1
    * @param row2
    */
   public int[][] sandPile( int n, int limitSupCase, String[] row1, String[] row2 )
   {
      logger.info( "sand Pile Addition" );
      int[][] array = new int[n][n];
      for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
      {
         String s = row1[i];
         for( int j = 0; j < row1.length; j++ )
         {
            String z = s.substring( j, j + 1 );
            array[i][j] = Integer.parseInt( z );
         }
      }
      for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
      {
         String s = row2[i];
         for( int j = 0; j < row2.length; j++ )
         {
            String z = s.substring( j, j + 1 );
            array[i][j] += Integer.parseInt( z );
         }
      }
      return formaterResultatSortie( distribuerGrainsSurCase( array, n, limitSupCase ), n );
   }

   private int[][] formaterResultatSortie( int[][] array, int n )
   {
      for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
      {
         for( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
         {
            //System.out.print( array[i][j] );
         }
         //System.out.println();
      }
      return array;
   }

   private int[][] distribuerGrainsSurCase( int[][] array, int n, int limitSupCase )
   {
      CaseTrouvee caseTrouvee = null;
      while( ( caseTrouvee = chercherCase( array, n, limitSupCase ) ) != null )
         distribuerSurLesCases( array, n, caseTrouvee, limitSupCase );
      return array;
   }

   private void distribuerSurLesCases( int[][] array, int n, CaseTrouvee caseTrouvee, int limitSupCase )
   {
      int i = caseTrouvee.i;
      int j = caseTrouvee.j;
      array[i][j] -= limitSupCase;
      if( i - 1 >= 0 && i - 1 < n ) array[i - 1][j] += 1;
      if( i + 1 < n ) array[i + 1][j] += 1;
      if( j - 1 >= 0 && j - 1 < n ) array[i][j - 1] += 1;
      if( j + 1 < n ) array[i][j + 1] += 1;
   }

   private CaseTrouvee chercherCase( int[][] array, int n, int limitSupCase )
   {
      for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
      {
         for( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
         {
            if( array[i][j] >= limitSupCase ) return new CaseTrouvee( i, j );
         }
      }
      return null;
   }
   class CaseTrouvee
   {
      public final int i;

      public final int j;
      public CaseTrouvee( int i, int j )
      {
         this.i = i;
         this.j = j;
      }
   }
}


@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
public class SandpileAdditionTest
{
   private static final Logger logger       = LoggerFactory.getLogger( SandpileAdditionTest.class );

   @Autowired
   private SandpileAddition    sandpileAddition;

   private static final int    limitSupCase = 4;

   private String[]            array1       = null;

   private String[]            array2       = null;

   private int[][]             expected     = null;

   private int                 matrixSize   = 0;
   /**
    * initialized parameters before test
    * 
    * 
    * @param testInfo : content parameters current test
    */
   @BeforeEach
   void initParams( TestInfo testInfo )
   {
      logger.info( "initParams" );
      switch( testInfo.getTestMethod().get().getName() )
      {
         case "sandpileAddition07Test":
            array1 = new String[] { "12123212", "21221323", "13231321", "30232213", "01123100", "32203321", "32303321", "32123321" };
            array2 = new String[] { "30321311", "20231002", "12303321", "31231321", "12312323", "13123121", "13132121", "32303321" };
            expected = new int[][] { { 2, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2 }, { 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 0 }, { 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1 }, { 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3 }, { 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1 }, { 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 0, 3 }, { 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3 }, { 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3 } };
            matrixSize = 8;
            break;
         case "sandpileAddition06Test":
            array1 = new String[] { "31003", "13120", "01310", "02131", "30013" };
            array2 = new String[] { "11111", "12221", "12321", "12221", "11111" };
            expected = new int[][] { { 2, 2, 1, 1, 2 }, { 2, 3, 3, 2, 1 }, { 1, 3, 2, 3, 1 }, { 1, 2, 3, 3, 2 }, { 2, 1, 1, 2, 2 } };
            matrixSize = 5;
            break;
         case "sandpileAddition05Test":
            array1 = new String[] { "1212321", "1221323", "1231321", "3032213", "0123100", "3203321", "3203321" };
            array2 = new String[] { "3032131", "0231002", "2303321", "1231321", "1232323", "1323121", "1332121" };
            expected = new int[][] { { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1 }, { 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3 }, { 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3 }, { 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 0 }, { 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2 }, { 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3 }, { 3, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3 } };
            matrixSize = 7;
            break;
         case "sandpileAddition04Test":
            array1 = new String[] { "121", "202", "121" };
            array2 = new String[] { "020", "202", "020" };
            expected = new int[][] { { 3, 1, 3 }, { 1, 0, 1 }, { 3, 1, 3 } };
            matrixSize = 3;
            break;
         case "sandpileAddition03Test":
            array1 = new String[] { "121321", "122323", "123121", "303213", "023100", "303321" };
            array2 = new String[] { "303213", "023100", "303321", "121321", "122323", "123121" };
            expected = new int[][] { { 0, 3, 2, 3, 3, 0 }, { 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2 }, { 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3 }, { 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 0 }, { 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 2 }, { 1, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2 } };
            matrixSize = 6;
            break;
         case "sandpileAddition02Test":
            array1 = new String[] { "000", "020", "000" };
            array2 = new String[] { "000", "020", "000" };
            expected = new int[][] { { 0, 1, 0 }, { 1, 0, 1 }, { 0, 1, 0 } };
            matrixSize = 3;
            break;
         case "sandpileAddition01Test":
            array1 = new String[] { "121", "232", "121" };
            array2 = new String[] { "303", "000", "303" };
            expected = new int[][] { { 2, 1, 2 }, { 1, 3, 1 }, { 2, 1, 2 } };
            matrixSize = 3;
            break;
         case "sandpileAddition00Test":
            array1 = new String[] { "121", "232", "121" };
            array2 = new String[] { "303", "000", "303" };
            expected = new int[][] { { 1, 1, 2 }, { 0, 3, 1 }, { 2, 0, 2 } };
            matrixSize = 3;
            break;
         default:
            break;
      }
      assertNotNull( sandpileAddition );
      logger.info( " begin " + testInfo.getTestMethod().get().getName() );
   }

   /**
    * destroyed parameters after test
    * 
    * @param testInfo : content parameters current test 
    */
   @AfterEach
   void destroy( TestInfo testInfo )
   {
      logger.info( "destroy" );
      String callingTest = testInfo.getTestMethod().get().getName();
      logger.info( " end " + callingTest );
      array1 = null;
      array2 = null;
      expected = null;
      matrixSize = 0;
   }

   @Test
   public void sandpileAddition07Test() throws Exception
   {
      logger.info( "sandpileAddition07Test" );
      assertEquals( true, compareMatrices( matrixSize, sandpileAddition.sandPile( matrixSize, limitSupCase, array1, array2 ), expected ) );
   }

   @Test
   public void sandpileAddition06Test() throws Exception
   {
      logger.info( "sandpileAddition06Test" );
      assertEquals( true, compareMatrices( matrixSize, sandpileAddition.sandPile( matrixSize, limitSupCase, array1, array2 ), expected ) );
   }

   @Test
   public void sandpileAddition05Test() throws Exception
   {
      logger.info( "sandpileAddition05Test" );
      assertEquals( true, compareMatrices( matrixSize, sandpileAddition.sandPile( matrixSize, limitSupCase, array1, array2 ), expected ) );
   }

   @Test
   public void sandpileAddition04Test() throws Exception
   {
      logger.info( "sandpileAddition04Test" );
      assertEquals( true, compareMatrices( matrixSize, sandpileAddition.sandPile( matrixSize, limitSupCase, array1, array2 ), expected ) );
   }

   @Test
   public void sandpileAddition03Test() throws Exception
   {
      logger.info( "sandpileAddition03Test" );
      assertEquals( true, compareMatrices( matrixSize, sandpileAddition.sandPile( matrixSize, limitSupCase, array1, array2 ), expected ) );
   }

   @Test
   public void sandpileAddition02Test() throws Exception
   {
      logger.info( "sandpileAddition02Test" );
      assertEquals( true, compareMatrices( matrixSize, sandpileAddition.sandPile( matrixSize, limitSupCase, array1, array2 ), expected ) );
   }

   @Test
   public void sandpileAddition01Test() throws Exception
   {
      logger.info( "sandpileAddition01Test" );
      assertEquals( true, compareMatrices( matrixSize, sandpileAddition.sandPile( matrixSize, limitSupCase, array1, array2 ), expected ) );
   }

   @Test
   public void sandpileAddition00Test() throws Exception
   {
      logger.info( "sandpileAddition01Test" );
      assertEquals( false, compareMatrices( matrixSize, sandpileAddition.sandPile( matrixSize, limitSupCase, array1, array2 ), expected ) );
   }

   /**
    * compare two matrix contents
    * 
    * @param n ; matrix dimension 
    * @param array : first matrix
    * @param expected : second matrix
    * 
    * @return return true if array is equals expected and false otherwise
    */
   private boolean compareMatrices( int n, int[][] array, int[][] expected )
   {
      assertNotNull( array );
      assertEquals( n, array.length );
      assertEquals( n, array[0].length );

      assertNotNull( expected );
      assertEquals( n, expected.length );
      assertEquals( n, expected[0].length );      

      for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
      {
         for( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
         {
            if( array[i][j] != expected[i][j] )
            {
               return false;
            }
         }
      }
      return true;
   }
}
```